# Include a json file with exe pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have been reading the [documentation of the pyinstaller](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/)  for hours. I cannot understand how to use the option `--resource RESOURCE`

It says

> `-r RESOURCE, --resource RESOURCE`
>
> > Add or update a resource to a Windows executable. The `RESOURCE` is one to
> > four items, `**FILE[,TYPE[,NAME[,LANGUAGE]]]**`. `FILE` can be a data file or an  exe/dll. For data files, at least `TYPE` and `NAME` must be specified. `LANGUAGE`  defaults to 0 or may be specified as wildcard * to update all resources of the given `TYPE` and `NAME`. For exe/dll files, all resources from `FILE` will be added/updated to the final executable if `TYPE`, `NAME` and `LANGUAGE` are omitted or specified as wildcard `*`. This option can be used multiple times.

I do not understand what `**FILE[,TYPE[,NAME[,LANGUAGE]]]**` means. This is the command I am using

`pyinstaller test.py -F -r=test.json`

Should it be `test.json[,JSON[,test]]`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Im not sure if you still need help, but this should help future people who come here from google. Use the spec file that is made when you first run pyinstaller on a py script. From there you can add json and other data files like below

```
 # -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

added_files = [
         ( 'configREs.json', '.'),  # Loads the '' file from
                                    # your root folder and outputs it with
                                    # the same name on the same place.
         ]


a = Analysis(['gui.pyw'],
             pathex=['D:\\OneDrive\\Programming\\Python Projects\\Python'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='name here',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False, icon='iconname.ico', version='version.rc' )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='gui')
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted the python application to exe with pyinstaller using below cmmand

```
pyinstaller --onefile main.py
```

and then I copied the json file to the dist folder created by pyinstaller and it worked. hope this helps you to resolve this issue.

Note : I havent included any resource command with pyinstaller