# How to include json in executable file by pyinstaller

Tags: python, json, pyinstaller, specifications

Tried to build `specs.spec` file with the following, to include a JSON file within the executable file.

```
block_cipher = None

added_files = [
         ( 'configREs.json', '.'),  # Loads the '' file from
                                    # your root folder and outputs it with
                                    # the same name on the same place.
         ]


a = Analysis(['gui.pyw'],
             pathex=['D:\\OneDrive\\Programming\\Python Projects\\Python'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=added_files,
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='name here',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=False, icon='iconname.ico', version='version.rc' )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='gui')
```

just like Clint recommended  in [add json file with pysintaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100198/include-a-json-file-with-exe-pyinstaller)

**BUT not working.**

1. Build spec file like so in the cmd - `pyi-makespec specs.py`
2. Then build Executable - `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --windowed --icon=logo1.ico script.py`
3. NOT WORKING without the JSON file placed in the same directory as the executable file
4. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is your json file name  ```configREs.json``` exists?

Comment: Your config seems fine how you call your json file in the code?

Comment: @py_saad yes. Different name but it exists in the same folder as the script.

Comment: @M.R. like so -    

`scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('configREs-.json', scope)


    client = gspread.authorize(credentials)`

Comment: @M.R. is there a way to write the content of the json file in the code, so it don't have to access it through a file?

Comment: Set the debug mode on https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/when-things-go-wrong.html and also, try with full-paths

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After you add your files with [`add-data`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) flag, on runtime those would be extracted into a temp directory like `C:/User/Appdata/local/temp/_MEIXXX`, so you need to load the files from this directory.

You can use [`sys._MEIPASS`](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/runtime-information.html#run-time-information) to get the current temp directory and load your file from there.

```
import os
import sys


def resource_path(relative_path):
    if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS'):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
    return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
             'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
        resource_path('configREs-.json'), scope)
    client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
```

Then generate your executable adding the `--add-data` flag:

> --add-data <SRC;DEST or SRC:DEST>
>
> Additional non-binary files or folders to be added to the executable. The path separator is platform specific, os.pathsep (which is ; on Windows and : on most unix systems) is used. This option can
> be used multiple times.

```
# The path separator is ; on Windows and : on most unix systems
pyinstaller -F --add-data "configREs.json;." script.py
```

Comment: Amazing! could it work to add the "driver" file as well? what adjustments should be made?

Comment: @Omri With the above function, you can load as many files as you want. Use `add-data` flag for each file.

Comment: I've tried to activate the exe on another computer and its failed. though on my computer it works - any ideas why's that?

Comment: "Failed to execute script SCRIPTNAME". I realized that --add-data is only for non-code files. My script is USING those files(JSON, driver.exe, icon.ico) in the code. So the problem is in the path, what do you think?

Comment: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

Comment: Windows --> `pyinstaller main.py --add-data "mappings.json;." main.py` Mac --> `pyinstaller main.py --add-data "mappings.json:." main.py`