# How do I create a .spec file from a python script and then run another python script to execute pyinstaller with that spec file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am trying to make a spec file to edit to package a json file with my .exe file for distribution. I have read the pyinstaller documentation on spec files (https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/spec-files.html) and it lead me to the documentation for creating a spec file ([https://pyinstaller.org/en/v4.0/spec-files.html#:~:text=The%20spec%20file%20tells%20PyInstaller,contents%20of%20the%20spec%20file.](https://pyinstaller.org/en/v4.0/spec-files.html#:%7E:text=The%20spec%20file%20tells%20PyInstaller,contents%20of%20the%20spec%20file.)).

In the documentation for creating the spec file, it says to run in the command line something like this:

```
pyi-makespec options name.py [other scripts …]
```

I am running my pyinstaller in a .py file using the PyInstaller.**main**.run function because my python distribution cannot be run in the terminal because it is not connected to the PATH variables due to work restraints.

Here is the code:

```
import PyInstaller.__main__

PyInstaller.__main__.run([
    'main.py',
    '--onefile',
    r'-i=some_picture.ico',
    '--noconsole'

])
```

Is there any way to create a spec file from a python file and run it through the above code? Am I following the right steps to include a json file with my exe file?

Thanks!

Edit: The next step after creating the spec file is referenced here ([Include a json file with exe pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42100198/include-a-json-file-with-exe-pyinstaller))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, you can execute command line code from a Python file using the `subprocess` module. Create a python file with the following template:

```
import subprocess

# Replace 'your_command_here' with the actual command you want to run
command = 'your_command_here'

# Run the command and capture the output
result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

# Print the output that you see in command line
print("Standard Output:")
print(result.stdout)

# Print the standard error that you see in command line
print("Standard Error:")
print(result.stderr)

# Print the return code that you see in command line
print("Return Code:", result.returncode)
```

In you case you should replace the following line with something like this:

```
command = "pyi-makespec options name.py [other scripts …]"
```

After creating the spec file, you can pass that `.spec` file in your `PyInstaller.__main__.run` method as an argument:

##### Solution 1

```
import PyInstaller.__main__

PyInstaller.__main__.run([
    'main.py',
    '--onefile',
    r'-i=some_picture.ico',
    'your_app.spec'

])
```

I don't think you need the `--noconsole` argument.

##### Solution 2

You can also do something like this:

```
import PyInstaller.__main__

# Construct arguments for PyInstaller
args = ['main.py', '--onefile', '--add data', 'image1.png:img' ,'--specpath', 'spec_file.spec']

# Run PyInstaller with the provided spec file
PyInstaller.__main__.run(args)
```